# Can the same method be called for different class variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to call the same method for a different variable as shown in the code.
In the example, I'm trying to get the double of a value by sending the name of the variable.

I've tried different approaches and none seems to work:

```
Class Number:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.num = a
        self.float = b
    def teste(self, val):
        print(2*self.val)

l=Number(3,9)
l.teste(a)
l.teste(b)
```

I expect the output to be 6 and 18

Comment: Yes, i know it doesn't but i want to access the object i just created and multiply the objects variable by 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it like this. When you call `l.teste(a)`, the name `a` refers to nothing, you'll get an error.

Even the `a` and `b` you used as parameters in `__init__` stop existing as soon as `__init__` exits, and can only be accessed from inside `__init__`.

What exists, though, is `self.num` and `self.float`. You can access them dynamically using [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), like this (note that we pass the name of the attribute as a string to getattr):

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.num = a
        self.float = b
    def teste(self, varname):
        print(2*getattr(self, varname))

l=Number(3,9)
l.teste('num')
# 6
l.teste('float')
# 18
```

Comment: Thank you very much, what i was looking for was the getattr() function.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in the code

- it's `class`, not `Class`
- as defined `num` and `float` are instance variables, not class variables
- last three lines are not part of the class definition, so they need to be unindented
- `float` is poor choice for property name (i.e. it imply that type is float, yet this is not enforced)
- `val` is not property of the class, but argument to `teste()` method. Thus you don't need `self.` when reference it.

Although I am not sure what the purpose is, you can achieve  what you want with

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.num = a
        self.float = b

    def teste(self, val):
        print(2 * getattr(self, val))

    def testb(self, val):
        print(2 * val)

foo = Number(3, 9)
foo.teste('num')
foo.teste('float')
foo.testb(foo.num)
foo.testb(foo.float)
# but you can do also for any number
foo.testb(10)
```

Note the difference between `teste()` and `testb()`

Comment: Thank you very much, what i was looking for was the getattr() function.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, thanks for fixing the indentation - Somehow I didn't notice my code had problem with the indentation when I paste it.